# After installing BIRT 4.4.2 all-in-one package I am not getting reports

Tags: birt

I recently installed the all-in-one package of BIRT 4.4.2 version. After that I prepared a demo report on it. But when I am running it or debugging it I am getting error. Do some plugins like Report engine etc. need to be installed after installing the Report Designer?

If yes, please someone give me step by step procedure of adding plugins.
I am getting the following error after running:

> Jun 04, 2015 11:34:49 AM
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher
>   renderReport SEVERE: Engine exception
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Failed to
>   initialize emitter.   at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLReportEmitter.initialize(HTMLReportEmitter.java:358)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.initializeContentEmitter(EngineTask.java:2320)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:118)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.createReport(ReportLauncher.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.renderReport(ReportLauncher.java:566)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.run(ReportLauncher.java:480)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.launcher.ReportLauncher.main(ReportLauncher.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.ReportDebugger.start(ReportDebugger.java:39)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Customers.rptdesign.html (Access is
>   denied)   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.EmitterUtil.getOuputStream(EmitterUtil.java:77)
>     ... 22 more
>
> Jun 04, 2015 11:34:49 AM
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.debug.internal.core.vm.ReportVMServer$1 run
>   WARNING: [Server] client disconnected

It would be grateful if someone could help me with this as I am completely new to this software.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, doesn't the exception already say it all?

java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Customers.rptdesign.html (Access is denied) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) ...

You are trying to create an output file \Customers.rptdesign.html at the root of your current disk and obviously you don't have write permission there.

Comment: Then in that case how can I give the write permission there?

Comment: stackoverflow.com is a place for developers. I can't teach you basic OS usage. Ask your admin or choose a different output directory.

Comment: Thanks,  you really deserve to be in a place which has "OVERFLOW" word in it cause your ego is overflowing .. Thanks for making me realize I don't belong here. PPL like you make me realize everytime never try for something new.

Comment: I'm sure hvb did not mean to sound condescending. They were just trying to point out it is probably an OS issue, outside of the Eclipse software. Choose a different location for your output files or go to the location where the files are currently being saved and give yourself permissions. Also, depending on the OS you use, check the account used to run Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If it is simply a permissions issue run the BIRT Designer or BIRT runtime as Administrator.